# How can I stop Runnable Handler in postDelay

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I'm new with Android... I developed an app which transition images by clicking a button and I add a Handler Runnable to get the images transition automatically (also when not pressing the button) with delay period of 5000ms. but I have to stop the Handler for this delay at the moment I press the button and I cannot do this for some reason.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Integer images[]={R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic21, ....
    public int currImage=0;
    public int ThreadCnt = 0;
    public boolean backInt=true,forwardInc=false, ThreadInc=true;
...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
    initializeImageSwitcher();
    setInitialImage();
    setImageRotateListener();  

   final Handler handler = new Handler();

            final Runnable run = new Runnable() {
                @Override
            public void run() {

    //forwardInc is a Boolean indicating that click button occurred
                if(forwardInc){
    //and in this case (of forwardInc=true) I want to stop runnable for 5sec
                    handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
                    forwardInc=false;
                    setInitialImage();
                    setImageRotateListener();
                    currImage++;
                    ThreadCnt++;
}
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);

  }
    };
    handler.post(run);
```

and this is the code for the button click

```
public void setImageRotateListener() {
        final Button rotatebutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRotateImage);
      rotatebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              currImage++;
 //forwardInc indicating that click button occurred
              forwardInc=true;
                ...
              setCurrentImage();
     ...
```

Comment: Call `handler.removeCallbacks(run)` to cancel that `Runnable`.

Comment: but I already add it in the if statement  in the run() method. handler.removeCallbacks(this);

Comment: @CommonsWare but I already add it in the if statement in the run() method. 'handler.removeCallbacks(this);'

Comment: That code is not connected to the button, at least based on what is in your code listings.

Comment: I don't see a proper logic in your code. Why are you setting `forwardInc= false;` inside the Handler? If you do so, the next time, it will return without doing anything. It will not even post the runnable after 5 secs.

Comment: @CommonsWare  I review my code again, you can see that the bottun click change `forwardInc`

Comment: @NabinBhandari I review my code again, please see that I want to set `forwardInc` to false in order to keep the Handler alive if next time click will not take place in the delay period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still not clear what you're trying to do. But as far I understand, try the following:

First, make the `Runnable` and the `Handler` global inside the class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){/**/}
    }
    //other declarations.
    //methods
}
```

Inside run method of runnable:

```
public void run(){
    setInitialImage(); //probably set next image
    currImage++;
    ThreadCnt++;
    handler.postDelayed( this, 5000 )
}
```

Now inside onClick:

```
public void onClick(View view){
    handler.removeCallbacks(this);
    handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    //no idea why you are using other code here.
}
```

And inside onCreate:

```
//other lines
setImageRotateListener();
handler.post(runnable);
```

Comment: Great!!! Your solution fix the problem. Can you please explain why it was essential to make `Runnable` and `Handler` Global, and why `handler.post(runnable);` should be inside onCreate. Thanks.

Comment: They are made global so that they can be accessed from any methods inside that class. `handler.post(runnable);` starts the `runnable`, so to start it in the starting of activity, it is inside `onCreate`.